# Tiny Validity class

Tags: c#, beginner, classes, constructor

Here is a part of my new code replacing the old and deprecated old-school one.

Let's get to business right away:

- I document everything with [Documentation comments](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/documentation-comments), which are proving very useful so far.
- I present you my new tiny class called `Validity`, of which goal is to indicate if something is valid or not, and if not, then there should be specified a reason for it.

Note: I actually tried to use `struct` instead, but as it appears, parameterless constructors are from C# >= 10 or something like that there.

There shall be absolutely no problem for you to review as I documented, well, everything. I welcome all of your tips to make it *perfect* as in more effective or better to use, safer, or whatsoever...

---

```csharp
/* I have a bunch of localized strings to my language. */
private const string INPUT_EMPTY = "Input is empty";

/// <summary>
///     <para>
///         Generic storage object for valid bools and various invalidity reasons.
///     </para>
/// </summary>
public class Validity
{

    /// <summary>
    ///     <para>
    ///         This indicates if something is valid or not.
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     <para>
    ///         If something is invalid, this indicates a reason for it.
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    public string ReasonForInvalid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     <para>
    ///         The default parameterless constructor assumes:
    ///         <code>
    ///             IsValid == true
    ///         </code>
    ///         and expects no reason for it whatsoever.
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    public Validity()
    {
        IsValid = true;
        ReasonForInvalid = "";
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     <para>
    ///         The second constructor assumes:
    ///         <code>
    ///             IsValid == false
    ///         </code>
    ///         and expects a reason for being invalid.
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    public Validity(in string aReasonForInvalid)
    {
        IsValid = false;
        ReasonForInvalid = aReasonForInvalid;
    }

}

/* Just to try it out, and declare something! :) */
Validity InputValidity = new Validity(INPUT_EMPTY);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Unnecessary `in` parameter

The `in string` parameter modifier is what sticks out the most. I'm not sure what benefit this has over a regular `string` parameter. Strings are allocated on the heap in C#, so all you ensure with the `in` modifier is that you get the same pointer... which you get anyways by passing it as a regular string. Furthermore, strings are immutable.

Specifying the `in` modifier is useful for value types where you do want to pass by value, but prevent the code in this constructor from modifying it.

If you desire immutability in your Validity class, refactor your properties to have a readonly backing field:

```
public bool IsValid { get; }
public string ReasonForInvalid { get; }
//                                   ^ (no 'set;' between the curly braces)
```

#### Unnecessarily Verbose Comments

The second thing that stands out are the comments. The comments seem rather verbose for what the class does. Consider rewriting the comments as quick one-liners. For example, the comment for the parameterless constructor is:

```
/// <summary>
///     <para>
///         The default parameterless constructor assumes:
///         <code>
///             IsValid == true
///         </code>
///         and expects no reason for it whatsoever.
///     </para>
/// </summary>
```

This can be rewritten as:

```
/// <summary>
///     Initialize a new Validity object marking it valid with no reason provided.
/// </summary>
```

Much more clear and concise. Likewise, the other constructor comment can be rewritten from:

```
/// <summary>
///     <para>
///         The second constructor assumes:
///         <code>
///             IsValid == false
///         </code>
///         and expects a reason for being invalid.
///     </para>
/// </summary>
```

To:

```
/// <summary>
///     Initialize a new Validity object marking it invalid for the given reason.
/// </summary>
```

#### Class Constraints Are Not Enforced

If a reason is required, then the following code should throw an exception:

```
new Validity(null);
new Validity("");
new Validity("  \t  ");
```

Consider checking `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aReasonForInvalid))` and throwing an ArgumentNullException if it returns true.

On a related note, `aReasonForInvalid` doesn't need the `a` at the beginning. Simply calling it `reasonForInvalid` is enough. The phrase "reason for invalid" is also not grammatically correct. It could be `reasonForInvalidity` or simply `reason` would work as well. Even naming the parameter `message` and the property `Message` would work.

#### All "Valid" Objects Are The Same

Consider the case where you want a "valid" validity object. Code will initialize a new object each time. Consider adding a public static field to represent a valid validity object:

```
public class Validity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a Validity object representing a valid value.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly Validity Valid = new Validity();

    private Validity()
    {
        IsValid = true;
    }

    /// <summary>...</summary>
    public Validity(string reasonForInvalid)
    {
        ...
```

Since the original code requires calling two different constructors (`new Validitory()` versus `new Validity(string)`) the static field allows you to give it a good name.

```
var validity = x > 5 ? Validity.Valid
                     : new Validity("x must be more than 5");
```

This allows your code to reuse the "valid" validity object, since the state of each "valid" object is the same. No need to allocate more memory to store the same exact values.